# Browser showing Aw Snap on loading large data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-chrome

I am loading data from MySql on local host xamp , for a report in HTML format.

The data returns records from multiple table joins and about 4000-5000 rows or even more . In my PHP script I have 4 loops which depends on each other to display data in HTML .

Instead of joining tables in a loop every time on the condition I need the data , I created a temporary table by joining other tables. Then I select records from it based on my condition. When data is small it loads successfully but when it is more the browser(chrome) shows AW Snap after few seconds .

I tried to set max execution time of PHP to more than 30s , increased memory limit but it didn't work .

Please help me to deal with the problem by providing a detailed description of why its happening and how to deal with it .

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Optimize your queries.

Comment: How to optimize?

Comment: For starters, check [this](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/5-tips-to-optimize-your-sql-queries).